# Incrementing variable count in AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I am building an agent-based-model in AnyLogic to show the progression of learners from one grade to the next throughout highschool. My states (Grade 8 up until Grade 12) have been drawn in my agent 'page' as shown below.

I have defined the transition rules for all states based on different agent variables. In order to see if my basic model is working, I have added `getMain().dropout_count++` to the 'Entry action' of my 'Dropout' state. I also have a variable called `dropout_count` in my Main simulation page that should show the how many learners have dropped out.

However, I can't get passed this point. I keep getting the error that

> The method `getMain()` is undefined for the type `Learner`

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? It seems like the most trivial error yet I have no I idea how to fix it.

[image]

Not sure why `getMain()` is not incrementing the `dropout_count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `main` or `get_Main()` (note the difference to your `getMain()`!!). Both work if your `Learner` is embedded into `Main` as an agent population.

If not, you can always brute-force using `((Main)getRootAgent)` instead.

In any case: start using code-complete as it tells you what you can and cannot code in any place: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/ui/using-intelli-sense.html

Last, understand your model hierarchy: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Benjamin. Will definitely be using code-complete from now on. You have truly helped me, much appreciated !